# The return type 'Null' isn't a 'Future<_>', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart

The return type 'Null' isn't a 'Future<_>', as required by the closure's context.
What the problem here ?

```dart
    void insertToDatabase() {
    database.transaction((txn){
      txn.rawInsert
        ('INSERT INTO tasks (title,date,time,status)VALUES("First task","0011","2430","New")')
          .then((value) {
        print('$value Inserted');
      }).catchError((error){
        print('error is ${error.toString()}');
      });

       return null;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately i got solved it :
go to pubspec.yaml 2)find this- environment: sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0" 3)change it environment: sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: But I think it might to changed return type on `insertToDatabase()`

Comment: Thasnks, it works

Answer (score 0):

Please forget that `then` exists and embrace the `async`/`await` style, it will make many things easier:

```
Future<void> insertToDatabase() async {
    await database.transaction((txn) async {
      try {
        final value = await txn.rawInsert
        ('INSERT INTO tasks (title,date,time,status) VALUES ("First task","0011","2430","New")');

        print('$value Inserted');
      } catch(error) {
        print('error is ${error.toString()}');
      }
    });
  }
```

You "solution" just *downgrades* Flutter so it cannot warn you about your problem anymore. It still is the same problem though, it did not go away.